# Broadcasting - 3D field of coefficients to 3D field of matrices given matrix basis

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a (large) 4D array, consisting of the 5 coefficients in a given basis for a matrix field. Given the 5 basis matrices, I want to efficiently calculate the matrix field.

The coefficient field `c[x,y,z,i]` being the value of i-th coefficient at position x,y,z

And the matrix field `M[x,y,z,a,b]` being the `(3,3)` matrix at position `x,y,z`

And the basis matrices `T_1,...T_5`, being the `(3,3)` basis matrices

I could loop over each position in space:

`M[x,y,z,:,:] = T_1[:,:]*c[x,y,z,0] + T_2[:,:]*c[x,y,z,1]...T_5[:,:]*c[x,y,z,4]`

But this is very inefficient. My attempts at using `np.multiply`,`np.sum` result in broadcasting errors due to the ambiguity of the desired product being a field of 3x3 matrices.

Comment: So in your text you mention that `M[x,y,z,a,b]` and then later when you calculate it `M[x,y,z]` Which one is the dimension? Can you provide a dummy example?

Comment: Quick comment, it appears that `np.apply_along_axis()` is a solution when supplied with a coefficient-->matrix conversion function.

Comment: That is a very inefficient way to attach your problem, since you are not having any laborious function that cannot be done with tensors. look at the `einsum`, you can pack `T_i` into one matrix, and then use tensor notation: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that to `numpy`, these 4 and 5d arrays are just that, not 3d arrays containing 2d matrices, etc.

Let's try to write your calculation in a way that clarifies dimensions:

```
M[x,y,z] = T_1*c[x,y,z,0] + T_2*c[x,y,z,1]...T_5*c[x,y,z,4]

M[x,y,z,:,:] = T_1[:,:]*c[x,y,z,0] + T_2[:,:]*c[x,y,z,1]...T_5[:,:]*c[x,y,z,4]
```

`c[x,y,z,i]` is a coefficient, right?  So `M` is a weighted sum of the `T_n` arrays?

One way of expressing this is:

```
T = np.stack([T_1, T_2, ...T_5], axis=0)   # 3d  (nab)
M = np.einsum('nab,xyzn->xyzab', T, c)
```

We could alternatively stack `T_i` on a new last axis

```
T = np.stack([T_1, T_2 ...T_5], axis=2)   # (abn)
M = np.einsum('abn,xyzn->xyzab', T, c)
```

or as broadcasted multiplication plus sum:

```
M = (T[None,None,None,:,:,:] * c[:,:,:,None,None,:]).sum(axis=-1)
```

I'm writing this code without testing, so there may be errors, but I think the basic outline is right.

It could also be written as a `dot`, if I can put the `n` dimension last in one argument, and 2nd to the last in the other.  Or with `tensordot`.  But there's less control over broadcasting of the other dimensions.

For test calculations you could also reshape these arrays so that the `x,y,z` are rolled into one, and the `a,b` into another, e.g

```
 M[xyz,:] = T_n[ab]*c[xyz,n]   # etc
```

Comment: Yes, `M` is simply the weighted sum of the basis arrays `T_n`. Thank you for the clarity note.